# AVR port transient characteristics

Tags: avr

While writing software for stepper motor drivers and tinkering with AVR timers I've notice something interesting (to me at least).

Enabling and disabling pin output on AVR port has strange transient characteristics. I've expected to see crisp ON/OFF signals between 0 and 5V (Vcc), but what I saw was peak-to-peek voltages greater than 7V:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm not an expert and can't find any information about transient characteristics of AVR ports. So I can't understand the reasons behind this observation (is it normal or not) as well as possible consequences for "down the line" components (should I protect then from negative voltages?).

Some additional information:

I'm using atmega 328p microcontroller on Arduino board. The problem only manifest itself when I'm using probes in 10x mode (Rigol DS1052E) with bandwidth limit OFF.

The source code – https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5bdf6395416f4f497754290b5cbf7bb7

Comment: What does the shape look like to you? What kind of device do you think could cause that? (Assuming for now that the scope and probe aren't the problem.) Do you think a capacitor might do that?

Comment: It is capacitance. You can see the discharge curve, in fact, that represents a capacitor and resistor, as the voltage falls back to its nominal level, again. Sharp *attack* followed by an RC decay curve. Clear case. Only question is, what capacitance and why is it there? Do you think you can work that out? Or figure out any tests?

Comment: Probing thechnique: are you using the long ground alligator clip with your probe, or the proper tiny ground spring?

Comment: Try to understand the step response of the output signal https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Step_response . Ideally you would get perfect square pulse but due to things you probably don't understand you will have some delay there in the rise of your signal (try to find some sources about "slew rate"), also you can see "overshoot" within each rise and "ringing", which is defined as a bump (or number of bumps after overshoot occurs). And for the end, ringing needs some time to settle down - which is called "settling time".

Comment: @peufeu, yes, I'm using alligator clip. I'll check if results with ground spring will be different. Thanks. But this effect doesn't manifest itself on built it oscilloscope 1kHz signal source.

Comment: @jonk, good idea. I'll check in this problem still present if I'm not using Arduino but single AVR chip on a breadboard. I don't think it's a capacitance because on a ON-OFF transient signal goes below GND. Capacitor can't do that. I'm a right?

Comment: Alligator clip adds lots of inductance in ground, and it can do weird things to the wave shape. Also, on a breadboard, or on a PCB without ground plane and solid decoupling, supply and ground will have inductance and there will be voltage bounce, which also mess with the wave shape.

Comment: @DenisBazhenov Yes, capacitors could ***easily*** drive the output below ground. In fact, I'd expect it. In this case, try and imagine the NFET and PFET devices being used to control the output. (I assume that when you write "enable" and "disable" you mean set to "1" and set to "0".) These have capacitance between their gates and their source and drain terminals. I may need to write an answer. But I was hoping you might "see" on your own here. If you thought closely enough about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll show you how to see this for yourself:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4LeSb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

That's a simplified behavioral diagram of the output pin. It's actually more complicated. But for these illustrative purposes, it's fine.

The output pin may be tied "HI" by turning \$M_1\$ *ON* and turning \$M_2\$ *OFF*. The output pin may be tied "LO" by turning \$M_1\$ *OFF* and turning \$M_2\$ *ON*.

If you place this into LTspice (and replaced that "square wave" thingy with an actual voltage source using rise and fall times close to \$1\:\text{ns}\$ or \$2\:\text{ns}\$, you'll see your spikes. Nice and pretty.

Your MCU is trying to drive the output quite quickly between two opposing values. But there is some capacitance between the output pin and the gates present within the driver circuitry. This is inescapable. It's a fundamental property of a MOSFET. I've added some capacitance here to exaggerate the details and make that visible to you. But it is there whether or not I add them to the circuit, explicitly.

When the MCU attempts to change the output, it does this by very rapidly changing the drive voltages to these gates. But the capacitors have some voltage across them that doesn't immediately vanish. It takes a moment to discharge. So for a very fast moment, their voltage "pushes" the pin further than expected (above the upper rail or below the lower rail.) Once that happens, a little time must also pass as these capacitors re-establish a new stable value. This is done through some resistance present. So you will see a sharp edge (the rate of change of which tells you a lot about how fast the internal drive circuitry can "move"), followed by a slightly more gradual relaxation as the capacitors regain a new balance. Your captured images show this behavior quite well.

Answer (score 0):

Consider how many wires are actually connected to your port, both externally and internally (circuit board and the chip itself). If the power to the port is cut-off or even changed then the magnetic field created by their inductance collapses giving you a small spike.
To be sure connect additional inductance and it should increase the spike. Not too much though as it might destroy something. You can create small inductances by rolling some wire into coils.

Comment: So you don't think that the OP needs to adjust the trimmer on his probes when fed with a known square wave then?

Comment: I supposed that it was already done...